# Database Schema Issue Regarding Table Implementation

Tags: sql, database, ios, sqlite

I am building an app which requires users to fill out a questionnaire on a daily basis. The questions are always the same. Essentially it is a diary system and 'entries' are made on a daily basis (each entry is the set of answers to the 5 questions on a particular date by a particular user).

My question is this:

What is the best way to orgabise this in terms of database schematics? I was thinking of having two tables:

```
Users:
username(pk)
password
.
.
diaryNo

Entries:
date(pk)
diaryNo(pk)
Qu1
Qu2
...
```

My problem with this is that the entry table will store entries for all users. A particulat entry can be mapped to a user by linking diaryNo. Obviously after a while, the entries table will become massive and sql performance will decrease.

This must be a common problem- are there any workarounds? better ideas for implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An index on either `Entries (diaryNo)` or `Entries (diaryNo,date)`, especially if you are selecting `Entries` based on `diaryNo` frequently. i.e. `diaryNo=?` appears in most of the select queries.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - PK should NOT have any business meaning - imagine what if user ask for change login. Just use simple autoinc.
You should use those tables:

```
Users (id(PK), username, ....)
Questions (id(PK), question, ....)
Answers (id(PK), userId(FK)(I), questionId(FK)(I), date(I), answer)
```